# Downloaded filename of file using X-Sendfile

Tags: php, apache2, x-sendfile

Im using X-Sendfile to send a file instead of readfile. The script processing this, is named download.php and contains this:

```
$video_file = '/path/to/file/file.mp4';
header('X-Sendfile: '.$video_file);
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; file=\"file.mp4\"');
exit();
```

But problem is that the downloaded file is always named "download.php" (155Mb), and i would like to download it named as file.mp4. Ive tried several things like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; file="file.mp4"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; file=file.mp4');
```

And all other posibilities, but still downloading the file as download.php.

My htaccess file contains: XSendFile On

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending an incorrect header. The filename property is called `filename`, not `name`:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.mp4"');
```

See [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) for a detailed description of the header.

Comment: done ;) im newbie in the community, was searching for the accepting button